# How to order relationships in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, relationship

I need help with Laravel 5.4.

I have 2 tables: origins and coffees.

An origin can have many coffees.

In my controller I have this:

`$origins = Origin::with('coffee')->get();`

Is it possible to order the result by origin name and coffee name, both in ascending order with Eloquent or do I need to us query builder?

Something like:

```
select coffees.name, origins.name
from coffees
join origins
on coffees.origin_id = origins.id
order by origins.name asc, coffees.name asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try if this gives you the results you want:

```
$origins = Origin::with(['coffee' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('name', 'asc');
}])->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
```